# JPA Many To Many Select

Tags: java, jpa

I got two entities FoaParamEmploye and FoaParamPosition (tables FOA_PARAM_EMPLOYE and FOA_PARAM_POSITION) with ManyToMany annotation (I didn't put here all attributes) :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOA_PARAM_EMPLOYE")
@NamedQuery(name = "FoaParamEmploye.findAll", query = "SELECT f FROM FoaParamEmploye f")
public class FoaParamEmploye implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private FoaParamEmployePK id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "FOA_PARAM_EMPLOYE_POSITION", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_EMPLOYE"), 
                        @JoinColumn(name = "COD_ENTREP") }
)
    private List<FoaParamPosition> foaParamPositions;
}
```

And the second one :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FOA_PARAM_POSITION")
@NamedQuery(name="FoaParamPosition.findAll", query="SELECT f FROM FoaParamPosition f")
public class FoaParamPosition implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private FoaParamPositionPK id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "FOA_PARAM_EMPLOYE_POSITION", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_POSITION"),
                        @JoinColumn(name = "COD_ENTREP") }
    )
    private List<FoaParamEmploye> foaParamEmployes;
}
```

Association table is `FOA_PARAM_EMPLOYE_POSITION` with `COD_ENTREP`, `ID_POSITION` and `ID_EMPLOYE` fields.

PK are :

```
@Embeddable
public class FoaParamEmployePK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     @Column(name="COD_ENTREP")
    private String codEntrep;

    @Column(name="ID_EMPLOYE")
    private long idEmploye;
}

@Embeddable
public class FoaParamPositionPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="COD_ENTREP")
    private String codEntrep;

    @Column(name="ID_POSITION")
    private long idPosition;
}
```

I try to get all FoaParamPosition for a FoaParamEmploye. I wrote this JPQL query :

```
Query q = entityMgr.createQuery(
    "SELECT position FROM FoaParamPosition position 
     INNER JOIN position.foaParamEmployes employes 
     where 
     employes.id.idEmploye = :idEmploye AND 
     employes.id.codEntrep =:codEntrep")
.setParameter("idEmploye", pIdEmploye)
.setParameter("codEntrep", "ENT");
```

I got an exception :

```
ORA-00904: "FOAPARAMEM1_"."FOAPARAMEMPLOYES_ID_EMPLOYE" : non valid identifier
```

As you can see, the generate SQL has this attribute but I can't understand why :

```
select
    foaparampo0_.COD_ENTREP as COD1_2337_,
    foaparampo0_.ID_POSITION as ID2_2337_,
    foaparampo0_.ACTEUR_MAJ_OCCUR as ACTEUR3_2337_,
    foaparampo0_.CD_PROFIL_AFFECTATION as CD4_2337_,
    foaparampo0_.CD_TYPE_PROFIL_POSITION as CD5_2337_,
    foaparampo0_.DATE_HEURE_MAJ_OCCUR as DATE6_2337_,
    foaparampo0_.DT_FIN_ACTIVITE_POSITION as DT7_2337_,
    foaparampo0_.HIERARCHIE_POSITION as HIERARCHIE8_2337_,
    foaparampo0_.ID_DIVISION_AGENCE as ID9_2337_,
    foaparampo0_.ID_EMPLOYE_PRINCIPAL as ID10_2337_,
    foaparampo0_.ID_REF_EXT_POSITION_PARENTE as ID11_2337_,
    foaparampo0_.ID_REF_EXTERNE_POSITION as ID12_2337_,
    foaparampo0_.NIVEAU_AGENCE as NIVEAU13_2337_,
    foaparampo0_.REF_EXT_POSITION as REF14_2337_,
    foaparampo0_.xqcif as xqcif2337_ 
from
    FOA_PARAM_POSITION foaparampo0_,
    FOA_PARAM_EMPLOYE_POSITION foaparamem1_,
    FOA_PARAM_EMPLOYE foaparamem2_ 
where
    foaparampo0_.COD_ENTREP=foaparamem1_.ID_POSITION 
    and foaparampo0_.ID_POSITION=foaparamem1_.COD_ENTREP 
    and foaparamem1_.foaParamEmployes_COD_ENTREP=foaparamem2_.COD_ENTREP 
    and foaparamem1_.foaParamEmployes_ID_EMPLOYE=foaparamem2_.ID_EMPLOYE 
    and foaparamem2_.ID_EMPLOYE=? 
    and foaparamem2_.COD_ENTREP=?
```

Comment: The prime suspect and your first area of investigation when wrong SQL is generated is that the mapping information is not correct. One thing I see is that there are not any inverseJoinColumns on those JoinTable annotations. This probably what you are seeing in the SQL is a default that the persistence provider is generating.

Comment: I remove inverseJoinColumns because I can't build project with them. There's 2 columns on primary keys, and inverseJoinColumns didn't like that. You can see explanations on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384449/a-foreign-key-refering-has-wrong-number-of-columns

Comment: I can recommend the following site: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence

Comment: can you add the code for FoaParamPositionPK

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to map your classes with some tool for example Netbeans -> generate JPA entities.
One of your side must be owning side (JoinColumn) and one must be inverse side (mappedBy).

If you don't wanna use any mapping tool, see this:

http://alextretyakov.blogspot.cz/2013/07/jpa-many-to-many-mappings.html

Comment: I can't use Netbeans, unfortunatly.

Comment: I'm sure there are other tools.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think if first you get an **FoaParamEmploye** object through below **JPA** query and after that use **getFoaParamPosition** method of this object to retrieve a list of positions your problem will get solved (when using this method in **many-to-many** association, the JPA will automatically retrieve the list):

```
Select distinct f from FoaParamEmployes f 
 where f.employes.idEmploye = :idEmploye
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I got the same error... ORA-00904: "FOAPARAMPO0_"."FOAPARAMPOSITIONS_ID_POSITION" : invalid identifier

Comment: You're welcome, sorry to hear that so it's need to review the code's more and check the fields name and etc, I hope you solve it soon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem in your mapping. The error you're getting complains explicitly about the invalid column name. In Oracle, the quoted names such as `"FOAPARAMPO0_"."FOAPARAMPOSITIONS_ID_POSITION"` are case sensitive, while the generated columns are `foaParamPositions_COD_ENTREP` and `foaParamPositions_ID_POSITION` and the case mismatch is causing your error.

A quick check would be to uppercase your *foaParamEmployes* and *foaParamPositions* and if I'm right the mentioned issue should be resolved. If so you can work-out a more elegant way to control the generated names with mappings.

I've noticed your other question in the comments referring to trouble with the *inverseJoinColumns*. That's why I'm mentioning upper-casing your properties. But in fact, you can handle it with mappings like

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name = "FOA_PARAM_EMPLOYE_POSITION", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_EMPLOYE"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "COD_ENTREP") }
,
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "FOAPARAMPOSITION_COD_ENTREP"), @JoinColumn(name = "FOAPARAMPOSITION_ID_POSITION")}
)
private List<FoaParamPosition> foaParamPosition;
```

and

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name = "FOA_PARAM_EMPLOYE_POSITION", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_POSITION"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "COD_ENTREP") }
        ,
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "FOAPARAMEMPLOYE_COD_ENTREP"), @JoinColumn(name = "FOAPARAMEMPLOYE_ID_EMPLOYE")}

)
private List<FoaParamEmploye> foaParamEmploye;
```

which solves the issue in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384449/a-foreign-key-refering-has-wrong-number-of-columns/27413033#27413033) I believe